# Reading Updatables Excel Columns using C#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am consuming an Excel spread sheet.
But I would like to know before implement..
If this sheet were updatables...

e.g

Let's suppose that the columns of my spread sheet
changes each second...

Would be a problem to the OleDB?
Should I call the `select` sql every second to be sure that I have the same values
or there are a better way to do this?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: What causes changes to the spreadsheet? Is it the user that types in new values? Is your spreadsheet automatically fetching data from some database or running VBA code?

Comment: @bouvierr It changes automatically.. I don't know how (programmatically).. I am getting the spreadsheet from the XP homebroker.. so I have no controll about when this will change... it will not insert new lines... just updates the existing.